# Calculate Price Method Not Working In Visual Studio

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

So I've made this form that acts as a cake shop. I have everything working perfectly except for the price. For some reason it isn't displaying properly and shows "$22.60" every time. I'm thinking there might be something wrong with the method

```
public virtual double CalculateCakeCost()
    {
        return CAKE_PRICE + (LAYER_PRICE * NumOfLayers);
    }
```

from class "Cake" since it seems to return the cake price, but not add it up with the bracket values. The calculate cost with tax method from the class "CustomCake" also seems to be working fine. You can read the rest of the code is down below and please tell me if there is a problem, because I don't see anything wrong.

```
namespace Lab_OrderCake_The_Bakery_
{

public partial class frmOrderCake : Form
{
    Cake objcake;
    CustomCake objcustcake;
    Customer objcustomer;
    Order objorder;

    public frmOrderCake()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void btnOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //flavour
        if (radVanilla.Checked == true)
        {
            txtRadFlavour.Text = "Vanilla";
        }
        if (radChocolate.Checked == true)
        {
            txtRadFlavour.Text = "Chocolate";
        }
        if (radBanana.Checked == true)
        {
            txtRadFlavour.Text = "Banana";
        }
        if (radLemonBerry.Checked == true)
        {
            txtRadFlavour.Text = "Lemon banana";
        }

        //layers
        if (rad1layer.Checked == true)
        {
            numRadLayers.Value = 1;
        }
        if (rad2layers.Checked == true)
        {
            numRadLayers.Value = 2;
        }
        if (rad3layers.Checked == true)
        {
            numRadLayers.Value = 3;
        }
        if (rad4layers.Checked == true)
        {
            numRadLayers.Value = 4;
        }

        //occassion
        if (radAnniversary.Checked == true)
        {
            txtRadOcc.Text = "Anniversary";
        }
        if (radBirthday.Checked == true)
        {
            txtRadOcc.Text = "Birthday";
        }
        if (radRetirement.Checked == true)
        {
            txtRadOcc.Text = "Retirement";
        }
        if (radWedding.Checked == true)
        {
            txtRadOcc.Text = "Wedding";
        }

        //size
        if (rad6inch.Checked == true)
        {
            numRadSize.Value = 6;
        }
        if (rad8inch.Checked == true)
        {
            numRadSize.Value = 8;
        }
        if (rad10inch.Checked == true)
        {
            numRadSize.Value = 10;
        }
        if (rad12inch.Checked == true)
        {
            numRadSize.Value = 12;
        }

        //design
        if (radPolka.Checked == true)
        {
            txtRadDesign.Text = "Polka Dots";

        }
        if (rad8inch.Checked == true)
        {
            txtRadDesign.Text = "Edible Images";
        }
        if (rad10inch.Checked == true)
        {
            txtRadDesign.Text = "Fondant Bow";
        }
        if (rad12inch.Checked == true)
        {
            txtRadDesign.Text = "3D Figures";
        }

        objcake = new Cake(txtRadFlavour.Text, (int)numRadLayers.Value);
        objcustomer = new Customer(txtFName.Text, txtLName.Text);
        objcustcake = new CustomCake(txtRadFlavour.Text, (int)numRadLayers.Value, txtRadOcc.Text, 
(int)numRadSize.Value, txtRadDesign.Text);
        objorder = new Order();

        lblOutOrder.Text = objcustomer.ToString() + objcustcake.ToString() + objorder.ToString();

    }
}



namespace CakeClasses
{
public class Cake
{
    public int NumOfLayers { get; set; }
    public string Flavour { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public const double CAKE_PRICE = 20;

    public const int LAYER_PRICE = 3;

    public Cake()
    {
        Flavour = "";
        NumOfLayers = 0;
    }


    public Cake(string flavour, int numLayers)
    {
        NumOfLayers = numLayers;
        Flavour = flavour;
    }

    **public virtual double CalculateCakeCost()
    {
        return CAKE_PRICE + (LAYER_PRICE * NumOfLayers);
    }**

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return " " + Flavour + " flavoured cake with " + NumOfLayers + " layer(s)";
    }
  }
}



namespace CakeClasses
{
public class Order
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Cake Cake { get; set; }
    public int NumOfCakes { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
        Customer = new Customer();
        Cake = new Cake();
        NumOfCakes = 1;
    }



    public Order(string fName, string lName, string flavour, int numLayers, string occasion, int 
diameter, string design)
    {
        Customer = new Customer(fName, lName);
        Cake = new CustomCake(flavour, numLayers, occasion,diameter,design);
        NumOfCakes = 1;
    }


    public Order(string fName, string lName, string flavour, int numLayers)
    {
        Customer = new Customer(fName, lName);
        Cake = new Cake(flavour, numLayers);
        NumOfCakes = 1;
    }


    public double CalculateCostWithTax()
    {
        return Cake.CalculateCakeCost() * 1.13;
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "for the total cost of " + CalculateCostWithTax().ToString("C");
    }
}
}



namespace CakeClasses
{
public class CustomCake : Cake
{
    public string Occasion { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public string Design { get; set; }
    private double DesignCost { get; set; }


    public CustomCake(string flavour, int numLayers,string occasion, int diameter, string design)
        :base(flavour,numLayers)
    {
        Occasion = occasion;
        Size = diameter;
        Design = design;
         switch (Design)
         {
             case "Polka Dots":
                DesignCost = 5;
                 break;
             case "Edible Images":
                 DesignCost = 12;
                 break;
             case "Fondant Bow":
                DesignCost = 10;
                 break;
             default:
                DesignCost = 15;
                 break;
         }
    }
    public override double CalculateCakeCost()
    {
        return base.CalculateCakeCost() + Size + DesignCost;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() +  " with " + Design + " design for " + Occasion + " occassion and 
size is " + Size + " inches " ;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try debugging the CalculateCakeCost method and seeing what the values are. It seems most likely that `NumOfLayers` is going to be 0

Comment: @devNull How can I check the value of NumOfLayers? And would you know how to fix it if it were 0? I think this is most likely the case.

Comment: If youre using visual studio you can set a breakpoint in your `CalculateCakeCost` method (click a line and press F9 key) and run your app in debug mode (press F5 key), then hover over `NumOfLayers` to see what the value is

Comment: Why on Gods green earth are you hard coding data in the year 2020. You have a data model in `Cake` which you need to populate from a file or db and then just use the form to **view** the data only.

Comment: what is the Type of `numRadLayers`
and what is the output you are seeing for `lblOutOrder.Text`

Comment: @Chronicle Ok yes I can see that the NumOfLayers is 0. How should I fix this? Also, in the ToString method below that, NumOfLayers is the value I want it to be because it shows up in the output. Why is that one ok but the other one is still 0?

Comment: @AbrahamKMS, `NumOfLayers =0` because you're only doing `order= new Order()` which calls `cake = new Cake()`. And `order.ToString()` is the only call that you are currently making that calculates the price of `cake` intialized from the default constructor

Comment: @AbrahamKMS, can you confirm if the below solution helped out, if yes, can you click the green tickbox to mark it as solved, so it would help somebody else in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing following line in your code:

```
objorder = new Order();
```

with:

```
objorder = new Order("First Name","Last Name",txtRadFlavour.Text, (int)numRadLayers.Value);
```